# Keep in array the latest item from date and from each category

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

In an array, I have a bunch of items with for each, a location ID and the date it has been created in the CMS (`created_on`).

```js
Array(50)
0:
created_on: "2020-04-22 07:10:00"
location: {id: "2"}

1:
created_on: "2020-04-22 07:15:00"
location: {id: "3"}

2:
created_on: "2020-04-22 07:13:00"
location: {id: "1"}

3:
created_on: "2020-04-22 07:12:00"
location: {id: "1"}

etc...
```

How to only keep the latest photo in date (from a `new Date()`) and from each location? Meaning each location would have only one photo, which is the closest in date.

I have in mind to remove the items not matching these two conditions, so if there is 3 locations, keep only 3 photos.

Comment: What is the expected output like?

Comment: @palaѕн I just have in mind to remove the items not matching the conditions. So in this case (I have 3 locations), only keep 3 items

Comment: Mind providing js fiddle link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

- Generate an object with `myPics.reduce()`
- Each iteration, check if the date is more recent than the current saved in the object for that location id
- If the date is more recent then overwrite the current saved in the object
- If no item is present at the location id (first for this location) save this item to the object
- Convert this object to an array with `Object.values()`

```js
const myPics = [
  {
    created_on: "2020-04-22 07:10:00",
    id: "1",
    location: {id: "2"}
  },
  {
    created_on: "2020-04-22 07:15:00",
    id: "2",
    location: {id: "3"}
  },
  {
    created_on: "2020-04-22 07:13:00",
    id: "3",
    location: {id: "1"}
  },
  {
    created_on: "2020-04-22 07:12:00",
    id: "4",
    location: {id: "1"}
  },
  {
    created_on: "2020-04-22 09:10:00",
    id: "5",
    location: {id: "2"}
  }
];

const myLatestPics = Object.values(myPics.reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  if (aggObj.hasOwnProperty(item.location.id)){
    if (new Date(aggObj[item.location.id].created_on) < new Date(item.created_on)){
      aggObj[item.location.id] = item;
    }
  } else {
    aggObj[item.location.id] = item;
  }
  return aggObj;
}, {}));

console.log(myLatestPics);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Negative numbers are **truthy** values which means that the `if (new Date(item.created_on) - new Date(aggObj[item.location.id].created_on))` condition doesn't do what you thing it does.

Comment: Already fixed it. Noticed it right after I posted and edited, Thanks for noticing :)

Comment: Insane! Thanks a lot @AlexL for your solution and the process behind, I could have never found that myself haha. Works like a charm!

Comment: You're very welcome. I often solve array problems with combinations of array methods like ``.map()``, ``.forEach()``, ``.filter()``, ``.reduce()`` and objects. Reduce is particularly powerful for problems like this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/es6/es6_arrays.htm